# Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in H:\php2\htdocs\property\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter i have started one property related project for my client.

I am getting an error

```
 Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in H:\php2\htdocs\property\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 233 after i have complete some development.
```

I have really search it for many time in google and in stackoverflow but still didn't get solved.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: and what exactly did u do?

Comment: your controller name???

Comment: my default controller name is Property.

Answer (score 1):

Well, m not sure but i guess it can happen because of changes in database settings. 
codeigniter sometimes show this very weird behaviour that giving this fatal error "CI_Controller" not found even there's nothing wrong with the core files.
so- try debugging like this-

1)check your database seetings located at config/database.php 
2)If it does'nt works, re-uploading the system files.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database config in **application/config/database.php** it's one of the major time consuming error message I faced with CI. Because the error message was simply misleading. So, check the database config first.